# grep the last occurrence of a pattern before another pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a huge file contains two types of patterns say **pattern1** and **pattern2**,  **pattern1** may appear many times before **pattern2** appears.
I want to grep the last occurrence of each **pattern1** before each **pattern2**.

Input file:

```
some text
pattern1=1
some lines
pattern1=2
some lines
pattern1=3
some lines
pattern2
some lines
pattern1=4
some lines
pattern1=5
some lines
pattern1=6
some lines
pattern1=7
some lines
pattern2
```

Desired output:

```
pattern1=3
pattern1=7
```

I tried with `grep` when I know the numbers of lines between **pattern2** and the previous **pattern1**:

```
grep -B400 "pattern2" | grep "pattern1"
```

but I need a unique command that can be run over any file regardless of the number of lines between the two patterns.

Comment: To be clear, you want to return the last instance of `pattern 1` that appears before any instance of `pattern 2` regardless of what other strings are between the two of them, yes?

Comment: Please read [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand the issue and then replace `pattern` everywhere in your question with whatever you really want to match - full or partial + word or line + string or regexp + anchored or not. Right now the answers you have assume you want unanchored partial line regexp matches which seems unlikely to be the most robust solution for you but that's based on what your code does since you haven't yet stated/shown what you actually need.

Comment: @NasirRiley yes exactly, anyway there are a lot of accepted answers for my quetion here

Answer (score 9):

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{x=$0} /pattern2/{print x}' input
pattern1=3
pattern1=7
```

Saves the `pattern1` matches (the whole line) to the variable `x` and prints that when `pattern2` happens. Will print a blank line if there's a `pattern2` before any `pattern1`, which would take more logic to detect if that's not desirable. Will drop any trailing `pattern1` that are not followed by a `pattern2` before the end of the input.

Answer (score 7):

@thrig's answer is good, but I made some modifications to handle some extra test cases. The following script:

- Will not print an empty line if `pattern2` appears before the first appearance of `pattern1`.
- Will not print duplicate lines if `pattern2` appears multiple times after `pattern1`.

With the modified input file:

```
pattern2
some text
pattern1=1
some lines
pattern1=2
some lines
pattern1=3
some lines
pattern2
pattern2
some lines
pattern1=4
some lines
pattern1=5
pattern2
some lines
pattern1=6
some lines
pattern1=7
some lines
pattern2
```

The following script seems to do what you describe in the text:

```bash
$ awk '/pattern1/{x=$0} length(x) && /pattern2/{print x;x=""}' file
pattern1=3
pattern1=5
pattern1=7
```

Answer (score 4):

Three `grep` calls:

1. Extract only lines that match `^pattern1=` or `^pattern2$` from the original input file

   ```bash
   grep -e '^pattern1=' -e '^pattern2$' file
   ```
2. Get the lines that match `^pattern2$`, and the lines immediately before these (using the non-standard `-B` option):

   ```bash
   grep -B1 '^pattern2$'
   ```
3. Get all lines matching `^pattern1=` from these:

   ```bash
   grep '^pattern1='
   ```

All together:

```bash
grep -e '^pattern1=' -e '^pattern2$' file |
grep -B1 '^pattern2$' |
grep '^pattern1='
```

This handles the same edge cases as [user000001's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714539/116858), namely that it does not output duplicate lines if there are many `pattern2` lins with no `pattern1` line between them, and it would not produce empty lines for `pattern2` lines at the start of the file.

---

Using `sed`:

```bash
sed -e '/^pattern1=/ { h; d; }' \
    -e '/^pattern2$/ x' \
    -e '/^pattern1=/ !d' file
```

1. If the current line is a `pattern1` line, it saves it into the hold space and discards it.
2. If the current line a `pattern2` line, it swaps in the hold space.
3. If the current line now is not a `pattern1` line, it is discarded.
4. (implicitly) print the current line.  The current line, by the preceding commands, must be a `pattern1` line swapped in from the hold space due to finding a `pattern2` line. The hold space would, therefore, by necessity, hold a `pattern2` line, ensuring that the `pattern1` line would not be outputted multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

```
❯ printf 'g/pattern2/?pattern1?p\n' | ed -s in.txt
pattern1=3
pattern1=7
```

Explanation:

`g/pattern2/` → For every match of the pattern2, do

`?pattern1?`  → Search backwards for pattern1

`p`           → print

Limitations:

1. Search backwards wraps back to end of file and selects the last match of pattern1
2. Prints the same line  multiple times if there are multiple `pattern2`

E.g.

```
pattern1=1
pattern2
pattern2
```

This will print pattern1 twice.

Comment: Could you use `/pattern1/,$` (or something like it) as the address range for the `g` command, possibly, to fix the wrapping issue? I'm on a phone and can't test...

Answer (score 3):

```
egrep "^pattern1|^pattern2" <file> | grep -B 1 "^pattern2" | grep "^pattern1"
```

The first egrep will get only the lines that contain either pattern (stripping all other unknown lines from the output).
The second grep will get the pattern2 and whatever line is before it.  This will be used to remove lines where there is no pattern1 before the pattern2.
The third grep will just return the remaining pattern1 lines.

Answer (score -2):

```
 awk '{a[++i]=$0}/pattern2/{for(x=NR-2;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' file1.txt| awk '/pattern1/'
```

output

```
pattern1=3
pattern1=7
```

As per Input pattern1 is separated by one line so used above awk command to extract the required output

Comment: You should probably mention the assumptions you're making, such as there not being more than two lines between the pattern. It's unclear why you have that second awk call, as you could do the same thing with an `if` statement in front of the `print`.

Comment: Think about the values your variable `i` will have. Now think about the values the builtin variable `NR` will have and figure out why introduce `i`.